# Badge on BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-layout, bottomnavigationview, material-components-android, material-components

I am trying to add a badge to the `BottomNavigationView` Item without using any library, however somehow the `BottomNavigationView` is not showing the badge (custom_view)

main_view.xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/activity_main"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context="com.hrskrs.test.MainActivity">

  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorAccent"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

bottom_navigation_menu.xml:

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <item
    android:id="@+id/item_test"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:title="action1"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

  <item
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:title="action2"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

  <item
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:title="action3"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Activity extended from `AppCompatActivity`:

```
@Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
    menu.clear();
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.bottom_navigation_main, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.item_test);
    item = MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, R.layout.custom_view);
    RelativeLayout badgeWrapper = (RelativeLayout) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

    TextView textView = (TextView) badgeWrapper.findViewById(R.id.txtCount);
    textView.setText("99+");

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
  }
```

custom_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@android:color/transparent"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="Notification Icon"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

  <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/txtCount"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_badge"
    android:text="55"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Istead of showing `(badge) custom_view` it shows the item itself only:

[image]

Below you can see from the debug mode that the `view` accessed is the right one and it is being set correctly. However somehow the `BottomNavigationView`is not being invalidated:

[image]

Comment: did u find any workaround for this ??

Comment: I answered this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42682855/display-badge-on-top-of-bottom-navigation-bars-icon/46595155#46595155.  I hope this helps.

Comment: This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56340643/11566969)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57073610/7254873

Answer (score 13):

You can use the [`BottomNavigationView`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/BottomNavigationView.md) provided by the [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).

Just add the `BottomNavigationView` to your layout:

```
  <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      app:menu="@menu/navigation_main" 
      ../>
```

Then use in your code:

```
  int menuItemId = bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).getItemId();
  BadgeDrawable badge = bottomNavigationView.getOrCreateBadge(menuItemId);
  badge.setNumber(2);
```

[image]

To change the badge gravity use the **`setBadgeGravity`** method.

```
badge.setBadgeGravity(BadgeDrawable.BOTTOM_END);
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I managed to make BottomNavigationView with the badge. Here is my code (Kotlin).

This is the panel (inherited from BottomNavigationView)

```
/** Bottom menu with badge */
class AdvancedBottomNavigationView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : BottomNavigationView(context, attrs) {

    private companion object {
        const val BADGE_MIN_WIDTH = 16          // [dp]
        const val BADGE_MARGIN_TOP = 5          // [dp]
        const val BADGE_MARGIN_LEFT = 15        // [dp]
    }

    @Inject internal lateinit var uiCalculator: UICalculatorInterface

    private val bottomMenuView: BottomNavigationMenuView

    init {
        //  Get access to internal menu
        val field = BottomNavigationView::class.java.getDeclaredField("mMenuView")
        field.isAccessible = true
        bottomMenuView = field.get(this) as BottomNavigationMenuView

        App.injections.presentationLayerComponent!!.inject(this)

        @SuppressLint("CustomViewStyleable")
        val a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.advanced_bottom_navigation_bar)
        val badgeLayoutId  = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.advanced_bottom_navigation_bar_badge_layout, -1)
        a.recycle()

        initBadges(badgeLayoutId)
    }

    /**
     * [position] index of menu item */
    fun setBadgeValue(position: Int, count: Int) {
        val menuView = bottomMenuView
        val menuItem = menuView.getChildAt(position) as BottomNavigationItemView

        val badge = menuItem.findViewById(R.id.bottom_bar_badge)
        val badgeText = menuItem.findViewById(R.id.bottom_bar_badge_text) as TextView

        if (count > 0) {
            badgeText.text = count.toString()
            badge.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            badge.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }

    /**
     * Select menu item
     * [position] index of menu item to select
     */
    fun setSelected(position: Int) = bottomMenuView.getChildAt(position).performClick()

    private fun initBadges(badgeLayoutId: Int) {
        // Adding badges to each Item
        val menuView = bottomMenuView
        val totalItems = menuView.childCount

        val oneItemAreaWidth = uiCalculator.getScreenSize(context).first / totalItems

        val marginTop = uiCalculator.dpToPixels(context, BADGE_MARGIN_TOP)
        val marginLeft = uiCalculator.dpToPixels(context, BADGE_MARGIN_LEFT)

        for (i in 0 until totalItems) {
            val menuItem = menuView.getChildAt(i) as BottomNavigationItemView

            // Add badge to every item
            val badge = View.inflate(context, badgeLayoutId, null) as FrameLayout
            badge.visibility = View.GONE
            badge.minimumWidth = uiCalculator.dpToPixels(context, BADGE_MIN_WIDTH)

            val layoutParam = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
            layoutParam.gravity = Gravity.START

            layoutParam.setMargins(oneItemAreaWidth / 2 + marginLeft, marginTop, 0, 0)
            menuItem.addView(badge, layoutParam)
        }
    }
 }
```

It's attr.xml file with options for this component:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="advanced_bottom_navigation_bar">
        <attr name="badge_layout" format="reference|integer" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Background for badge from drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Badge itself:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_bar_badge"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/bcg_badge"
    >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_bar_badge_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="1"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

And this is an example how to use it in your code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="su.ivcs.ucim.presentationLayer.userStories.mainScreen.view.MainActivity">

    <su.ivcs.ucim.presentationLayer.common.advancedBottomNavigationView.AdvancedBottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@android:color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/main_screen_tabs_menu_items"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/main_screen_tabs_menu_items"
        app:menu="@menu/main_screen_tabs_menu"
        app:badge_layout = "@layout/common_badge"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fragmentsContainer"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: what is the UICalculatorInterface ??

Comment: @MuneerahRashed It's my helper for UI measures calculations - sizes etc. For this solution, it's not essential.

Answer (score 1):

@hrskrs Try adding a higher elevation on your txtCount or badgeWrapper itself.
`BottomNavigationView` seems to have higher elevation than the views on the screen.

I struggled with showing badges on `BottomNavigationView` items. My badge (without any text value) being part of the drawable itself turned grey when user clicked other item or became the same color defined in the tint (if not defined is colorPrimary). 
I think you will run into the same problem I faced with colouring of the badge/counter on top of menu item of `BottomNavigationView`as tint color will be applied to the item itself and your badgeWrapper being part of `MenuItem` will take the tint (turns grey when you tap any other item which you will not want I guess).

Check out my answer here: [Is there a way to display notification badge on Google's official BottomNavigationView menu items introduced in API 25?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42377819/is-there-a-way-to-display-notification-badge-on-googles-official-bottomnavigati)

I used an `ImageView` for a badge but you can have your badgeWrapper `RelativeView` instead of the ImageView.

Comment: I am not asking for an alternative as there are multiple ways to achieve it. I am asking to add badge to `BottomNavigationView` through `Menu resources`

Comment: I struggled with Menu Resources and it didn't work for me. Doing it with menu resources would be the correct way. I will be glad to see if you get it working with menu resources.

Answer (score 0):

use the [BadgeDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/badge/BadgeDrawable) like this:

```
Integer amount = tabBadgeCountMap.get(tab);
            BadgeDrawable badgeDrawable = bottomNavigationView.getOrCreateBadge(tabMenuResId);
            badgeDrawable.setNumber(amount != null ? amount : 0);
```