# Android Bottom navigation- adding notification badge

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I am using bottom navigation bar for my app. I want to display notification badge on it. 
Here is my code for

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"            android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
        android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_item_selector"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_nav_bottom"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        ></android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display badge on top of bottom navigation bar's icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42682855/display-badge-on-top-of-bottom-navigation-bars-icon)