# How to add notification badge on Bottom Navigation View?

Tags: android

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.TextView"/>
```

This is the menu of bottom Navigation.

```
   TextView gallery=(TextView)  
   MenuItemCompat.getActionView(navigationView.getMenu().
   findItem(R.id.nav_gallery)); //getting menu item of bottom nav view
   gallery.setText("99+");
```

But this code doesnot work for bottom navigation view.BottomNavigationView is shown without setting any notification counter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display badge on top of bottom navigation bar's icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42682855/display-badge-on-top-of-bottom-navigation-bars-icon)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57073610/7254873

Answer (score 4):

The Latest Material dependency now supports natively add badge count, Need to just updated Material dependency in build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09'
```

and just add

```
val navBar  = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_navigation)
navBar.getOrCreateBadge(R.id.action_stamp).number = 2
```

and in style.xml just change "AppCompat" to "MaterialComponents"

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Comment: I think in the end, you must set `isVisible = true`

Comment: In case, if your count exceeds a certain limit and you want to show truncated  version of count, you can use `setMaxCharacterCount(int maxCharacterCount)`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly create a layout file of your badge, then follow these steps

```
BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) navigation.getChildAt(0);
 
BottomNavigationItemView itemView = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(2);

View messageBadgeView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.message_badge_view, menuView, false);    
TextView textView = messageBadgeView.findViewById(R.id.counter_badge);        
textView.setText("15");

itemView.addView(messageBadgeView);`
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way for those who couldnt access the `getOrCreaeteBadge` is to use the method below;

1. Make sure your theme on your bottom Navigation is set on:
   `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar`
2. Then now:

   ```
    String messages = getIntent().getStringExtra("messages_count");
    messages = messages.substring(10,11);
    Log.d("MessagesCount", "getIncomingIntent: "+messages);
    navigation.showBadge(R.id.bottom_messages).setNumber(Integer.parseInt(messages));
   ```

And you're good to go! Sample output is below

[image]

Comment: there is no such method as `showBadge` in `com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView`

Comment: make sure you import the dependency `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06`

Comment: The material dependency makes no difference. ShowBadge is a custom method.