# Android Bottom Navigation View multicolored icon

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I have a bottom navigation view with 4 icons, one of them being a notification icon.I have to notify when there are new notifications, I am doing that by changing the icon programmatically to  [image: Icon]

The problem is at runtime the red dot is also grey. 
[image: At runtime]
The icons are by default set to grey and on selection it takes primary color of the app (incase no iconTint color is set). If I set the IconTint color to red then the whole image is red instead of just the red dot. I want to show the image as is and not have the background color effect on it. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
final Menu menu =bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            MenuItem notificationItem=menu.findItem(R.id.action_notification);
            notificationItem.setIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon_with_badge);
        }
    });
```

Thanks

P

Comment: In android version 25.0 they added new class. Just take a look into below link.https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html

Comment: Did you find a solution to this yet?

Comment: unfortunately no :(

Comment: this duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42682855/display-badge-on-top-of-bottom-navigation-bars-icon

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with the following also

place 2 images in the drawable folder, one with the red dot one with grey

and then on if conditions you can setimageresource(R.drawable.yourimagename)

Comment: I am updating the menu item icon at runtime using condition check and that works fine, the problem is even though the image is grey with red dot, at runtime the whole image is grey even the red dot is grey. I dont see a setImageResource method on MenuItem.

Comment: try setIcon with 2 images. one with red one with grey

Comment: I have tried setting 2 icons but it doesnt work. Both the icons are grey. The red dot does not show.

Comment: no i meant, one icon should be with the grey dot, the other with the red dot. dont separately add the red dot :)