# Android BottomNavigationView with Badge

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross, bottomnavigationview

There is no support for adding badges to the BottomNavigationView in Android.

How can I add a badge with a number to a specific tab in the BottomNavigationView. I need it to be done natively with no third party libraries.

I am using Xamarin native with MvvmCross.

Comment: Oh well. I had a problem, found the answer and thought it would be nice to let others know, especially after reading "Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions". Not sure what is "Too broad" about the question, especially when the question has been asked before, but I require the use of no third party libraries.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**---Note---**

Badges will soon be supported out the box. However this might be useful if you really want to add custom views to your tabs.

**Create Layout With BottomNavigationView**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabsRootFrameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tabsRootBottomNavigation" />
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/tabsRootBottomNavigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        local:menu="@menu/root_bottom_navigation_menu"
        local:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navigation_selector"
        local:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_navigation_selector"
        local:elevation="16dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Menu: root_bottom_navigation_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/tab_search"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/search_icon"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/tab_profile"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/profile_icon"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/tab_my_car"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/car_icon"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/tab_notifications"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/bell_icon"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

**Create Badge Layout: component_tabbar_badge.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin_tiny">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notificationsBadgeTextView"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/notification_red_dot"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="9dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**Red Dot Background: notification_red_dot.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid
        android:color="@color/red" />
    <size
        android:width="10dp"
        android:height="10dp" />
</shape>
```

**Add Badge Layout To Bottom Navigation**

```
private void SetNotificationBadge()
{
    _bottomNavigation = FindViewById<BottomNavigationView>(Resource.Id.tabsRootBottomNavigation);
    var notificationsTab = _bottomNavigation.FindViewById<BottomNavigationItemView>(Resource.Id.tab_notifications);
    View badge = LayoutInflater.From(this).Inflate(Resource.Layout.component_tabbar_badge, notificationsTab, false);
    _notificationBadgeTextView = badge.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.notificationsBadgeTextView);
    notificationsTab.AddView(badge);
}
```

**Bind Badge Text**

```
    var set = this.CreateBindingSet<TabsRootActivity, TabsRootViewModel>();
    set.Bind(_notificationBadgeTextView).To(vm => vm.UnreadNotificationsCount);
    set.Apply();
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: how to remove if 0

Comment: `_notificationBadgeView.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone`

Answer (score 0):

This Helps You More

Ref: [Display badge on top of bottom navigation bar's icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42682855/display-badge-on-top-of-bottom-navigation-bars-icon)

When using the support library Bottom Navigation bar, it's quite complex to show a badge/notification on menu items. However, there are easy solutions to get it done. Such as https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation

This library is a more advanced version of the Bottom Navigation bar. And you can set a badge on menu item simply using this code snippet.

```
bottomNavigation.setNotification(notification, bottomNavigation.getItemsCount() - 1);
```

> if you don't want use third-party library's then no problem

Take A Look For More Info 
[Display badge on top of bottom navigation bar's icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42682855/display-badge-on-top-of-bottom-navigation-bars-icon)