# Error : IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, bottombar

Below are my dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

My layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
        app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"
        app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="4dp"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_drawer" >

    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomBar"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_apps" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The Above code is working fine for me

But when i update the `dependencies` of `material design`

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha01'
```

I'm getting below error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{neel.com.bottomappbar/neel.com.bottomappbar.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2485)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2545)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1396)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:543)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at neel.com.bottomappbar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:16)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6358)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2438)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2545) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1396) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:649)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:768)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:839)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at neel.com.bottomappbar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:16) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6358) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2438) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2545) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1396) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:623)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:768) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:839) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at neel.com.bottomappbar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:16) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6358) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2438) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2545) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1396) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:240)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkMaterialTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:215)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:143)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:78)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
```

Answer (score 130, accepted):

There is some issue with `material:1.1.0-alpha01`

A simple solution is to change the parent theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
       
</style>
```

Comment: Issue still exists in `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0`.

Comment: I got the same issue in `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0` but solved that by changing the parent theme.

Comment: This is working but might change your design a bit.

Comment: Solution #1 works. Issue still persists wit Solution #2.

Comment: This changes view of components, so design.. And this is what said by Android Studio anyway.. This is not good solution

Comment: It's recommended to use `.Bridge` Theme, such as `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar.Bridge`, as you can use Material Design components without changing your app theme. See https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started#bridge-themes

Answer (score 78):

Extend your base app Theme from Material Components **Bridge** theme. It extends AppCompat theme, but adds all necessary stuff.

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge">
    <!-- ... -->
</style>
```

> Both `Theme.MaterialComponents` and `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light` have `.Bridge`  themes:
>
> `Theme.MaterialComponents.Bridge`
> `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge`
> `Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar.Bridge`
> `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge`
> `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar.Bridge`

It allows you to keep using latest version of the library, but avoid a lot of UI issues, caused by migration to pure Material Component theme

https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/#bridge-themes

Answer (score 58):

Adding theme directly to widget works too. E.g.:

```xml
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
        android:id="@+id/toggle_button_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"> <======== THIS
```

Checked with min. SDK ver. 21.

Comment: How can I do it for programmatically created chip?

Comment: Thats way better than changing entire app theme

Comment: @FazalHussain `new Chip(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.Theme_MaterialComponents_Light));`

Comment: This worked for me. For some Reason my  CustomAdapter was unable to get the app theme and I had to add it in that xml.

Comment: This works great instead of changing the whole app theme. Thanks!!

Answer (score 17):

None of these worked for me. Must do these two things.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme -->
</style>
```

and

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    app:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents"
```

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: adding theme in both the places solved the problem, thanks

Answer (score 10):

**|> 1:** Define the following style in `style.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme -->
</style>
```

**|> 2:** In the `manifest.xml` file, use from above style:

```
<application
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"> <!-- IMPORTANT (This was my mistake) -->
</application>
```

**|> 3:** Choose a style for your component:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"
...
>
</com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I believe this one should be the best answer because you are the only one who mentioned that the change should be made in style.xml file. (which is in the values folder)

Answer (score 7):

We have change Gradle dependencies and style code my case working fine

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/drawer_list_selector</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/black_overlay</item>
    <!--<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/nav_menu_background</item>-->
</style>
```

Gradle Dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also add theme to CoordinatorLayout, such as

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar.Bridge"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're having this issue and you're instantiating a view programmatically:

Make sure not to use getApplicationContext() when requiring a Context instance, but instead use `this` or `HolderActivity.this` (replace HolderActivity with your own activity) if inside a anonymous function.

For example I was having this issue with

```
CustomAlertDialogBuilder builder = new CustomAlertDialogBuilder(getApplicationContext());
```

where I should be using

```
CustomAlertDialogBuilder builder = new CustomAlertDialogBuilder(MyActivity.this);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when I was testing the **TextInputEditText** which was inside a **TextInputLayout** with style that had parent **parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"**

And the solution was to add the theme in the tests as follows

```
val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer<Fragment>(themeResId = R.style.Theme_APP)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are adding a view into WindowManager you must set style into your layout
like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/parentView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.YOUR_THEME"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an error when I create a chip in code, This issue makes the app stop working, so I solved with creating a chip with context like your activity name like below

```
Chip chip = new Chip(YourNameActivity.this);
```

It works for me, my app use dependency as `com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0`

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and fixed it by changing the theme "Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar" with "Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge" and this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Changing Gradle Dependencies to this did the work!

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
```

P.S. Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1