# Android Material TextInputLayout Style OutlinedBox Not Working

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, material-components-android

I use Material TextInputLayout with style OutlinedBox

```
@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox
```

It's not working when start emulator "Unfortunately has Stopped."

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'



<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:inputType="text" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Error Run Activity logs

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.mcic.drawer, PID: 8832
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mcic.drawer/com.mcic.drawer.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
> at com.mcic.drawer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:9)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696) 
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170) 
> at com.mcic.drawer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:9) 
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
> at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:248)
> at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkMaterialTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:222)
> at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:150)
> at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainTintedStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:120)
> at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.(TextInputLayout.java:424)
> at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.(TextInputLayout.java:396)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696) 
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170) 
> at com.mcic.drawer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:9) 
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Comment: Post the stacktrace

Comment: Duplicate of [Error : IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53476115/208273)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error : IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53476115/error-illegalargumentexception-the-style-on-this-component-requires-your-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you view the run output, you will see:

> The style on this component requires your app theme to be
> Theme.MaterialComponents

So we could change the app theme inherited from `Theme.MaterialComponents`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar.Bridge">
```

The detailed explanation is [here](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started).