# How to display badge on items of bottomNavigationView android?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I saw this question - [Display badge on top of bottom navigation bar's icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42682855/display-badge-on-top-of-bottom-navigation-bars-icon) and decided to add my own custom badges to my bottomNavigationView. Firstly, I have created special layout of my badge:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/counter_badge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/badge"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

then I add some info to badge textView at my activity:

```
BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) bottomNavigationView.getChildAt(0);
BottomNavigationItemView itemView = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(0);

notificationBadge = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.notification_badge, menuView, false);
TextView textView = notificationBadge.findViewById(R.id.counter_badge);

textView.setText("15");

itemView.addView(notificationBadge);
```

but as I see I can work with only one item of my view, when I tried to change from 0 to 1 item, I received this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView.getChildAt(int)' on a null object reference
```

then I tried to use special ids of items, but I receive similar error. Maybe smb know how to add badges to items which I want?

Comment: perhaps you should change `menuView.getChildAt(1);` ?

Comment: you can add the custom layout in your bottomnav menu

Comment: @JohnJoe, when I change this I receive error at the `BottomNavigationItemView itemView = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(0);`

Comment: @HussainAbbas, I looked through all possible libraries, but then I decided to create my own badge

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko use custom layouts and add it into your menu

Comment: @HussainAbbas, can you explain more please, because I didn't understand what you meant?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko first create your xml layout in which you can add you textview and image the one you are using in bottom nav after that goto your menu file use action layout inside the item and add your layout the one you created there after that access your menu view using menu view acess  text view and add some text in it

Comment: do you understand?

Comment: can you check the second answer at my question, maybe it will help me? because I guess that I have completely understand your comment :)

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko try john joe's Answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57073610/7254873

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your code to this

```
BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) bottomNavigationView.getChildAt(0);
BottomNavigationItemView itemView = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(1);
```

**Edit**

To have more items having badge, you need to create another layout and so on

```
BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) bottomNavigationView.getChildAt(0);
BottomNavigationItemView itemView = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(0);

notificationBadge = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.notification_badge, menuView, false);
TextView textView = notificationBadge.findViewById(R.id.counter_badge);
textView.setText("15");
itemView.addView(notificationBadge);

BottomNavigationMenuView menuView1 = (BottomNavigationMenuView) bottomNavigationView.getChildAt(0);
BottomNavigationItemView itemView1 = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView1.getChildAt(1);

notificationBadgeOne = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.notification_badge_one, menuView1, false);
TextView textView = notificationBadgeOne.findViewById(R.id.counter_badge);
textView.setText("15");
itemView1.addView(notificationBadgeOne);
```

Comment: and how I can add badge to some more items, not only for one single?

Comment: Then you need to have another custom layout.

Comment: so if I have 5 items, I have to use 5 different layout?

Comment: Not sure is this the best approach, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

This is now possible without custom views using

`com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06`

and newer versions

```
  bottomNavigationView.getOrCreateBadge(R.id.bottom_navigation_view_item).apply {
  backgroundColor = Color.RED
  badgeTextColor = Color.WHITE
  maxCharacterCount = 3
  number = 0
  isVisible = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add badge on BottomNavigationView as :

```
 private lateinit var bottomNavItemView: BottomNavigationItemView
 private var messageBadgeView: View? = null

 val mBottomNavigationMenuView = getChildAt(0) as BottomNavigationMenuView
 val view = mBottomNavigationMenuView.getChildAt(1)
 bottomNavItemView = view as BottomNavigationItemView

 messageBadgeView = LayoutInflater.from(this@Activity)
          .inflate(R.layout.item_message_count_badge,
                        mBottomNavigationMenuView, false)

 messageBadgeView!!.badgeCount.text = "99+"

 //Add badge
 bottomNavItemView.addView(messageBadgeView)

 //Or Remove badge
 bottomNavItemView.removeView(messageBadgeView)
```

Comment: I'm using java at my project :( can you add java code?

Comment: OP want to have  badge on more items.

Comment: Yes!! you can understand kotlin code if you give some time for basic syntax

Comment: And for more badges need to inflate more badge items for specific BottomNavigationItemView items

Answer (score 1):

Another way for those who couldnt access the `getOrCreaeteBadge` is to use the method below;

1. Make sure your theme on your bottom Navigation is set on:
   `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar`
2. Then now:

   ```
    String messages = getIntent().getStringExtra("messages_count");
    messages = messages.substring(10,11);
    Log.d("MessagesCount", "getIncomingIntent: "+messages);
    navigation.showBadge(R.id.bottom_messages).setNumber(Integer.parseInt(messages));
   ```

And you're good to go! Sample output is below

[image]