# Add Icon after Text Label In Bottom Navigation

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I am not able to find a way to add little Red Dot just after bottom navigation label as in image.

Currently it is having Icon + label and I wan to add red dot. Is there any way?

### Current

[image]

### Looking For

[image]

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42682855/display-badge-on-top-of-bottom-navigation-bars-icon

Comment: Do you mean I will have to set the badge for this? In fact, I want red dot always to be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This what I have done to achieve what I was looking for. This is the most simpler way I found without using any heavy coding or library.

```
Menu menu = navigation.getMenu();
MenuItem live_one = menu.findItem(R.id.navigation_live_one);
MenuItem live_two = menu.findItem(R.id.navigation_live_two);

String text = "<font color='white'>Live</font> <font color='red'>&#11044;</font>";
live_one.setTitle(Html.fromHtml(text));
live_two.setTitle(Html.fromHtml(text));
```