# Bottom navigation view dot on the top of icon

Tags: java, android, xml, bottomnavigationview

I want my bottom `nav bar` like this image. I tried using a "." in label field but it did not work any suggestion how can we achieve this

[image]

Comment: Tell us what you have accomplished so far , nobody is going to write code for you.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42682855/display-badge-on-top-of-bottom-navigation-bars-icon.

Answer (score 1):

The dot only appears on the selected item; so I suggest to add the dot on the icon, in that way you will have to icons for each item (selected and not selected). Then, you should use a drawable for the background of the item. Each item should be like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_with_dot"android:state_selected="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_without_dot" android:state_pressed="true" />
```